# Is there a concise way to initialize a message with specific values?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever I need to instantiate a message with specific values (in test code, for example), I end up writing something like this:

```
geometry_msgs::msg::Pose my_pose;
my_pose.position.x = 0.1;
my_pose.position.y = 0.2;
my_pose.position.z = 0.3;
my_pose.orientation.x = 0.5;
my_pose.orientation.y = 0.5;
my_pose.orientation.z = 0.5;
my_pose.orientation.w = 0.5;
```

Is there a more concise way to do this? I was hoping for something closer to a uniform initialization approach like below, but it doesn't seem to play nicely with how the message classes are implemented.

```
geometry_msgs::msg::Pose my_pose{ geometry_msgs::msg::Point { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 }, geometry_msgs::msg::Quaternion { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 } };
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399059/is-there-a-concise-way-to-initialize-a-message-with-specific-values?/) by [jschornak](https://answers.ros.org/users/37574/jschornak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2022-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can write like [this](https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.universe/blob/1e829e2948222e8b9c60a2af3bf3008ffbe2ec6d/common/tier4_autoware_utils/include/tier4_autoware_utils/geometry/geometry.hpp#L42).

```
geometry_msgs::build<geometry_msgs::msg::Point>().x(p.x).y(p.y).z(p.z);
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/issues/447#issuecomment-598003951) for details.

---

Originally posted by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) with karma: 307 on 2022-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2022-04-15**:
Nice pattern! This should be better documented somewhere.

**Comment by [jschornak](https://answers.ros.org/users/37574/jschornak/) on 2022-04-15**:
Neat! What is the correct header to include for a particular message type? For `geometry_msgs::msg::Point` I see `#include <geometry_msgs/msg/detail/point__builder.hpp>`, but the structure of the path to the header kinda implies that this is part of the internal API.

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2022-04-15**:
@jschornak I believe the message header will give you access to this templated `build` function too since `<geometry_msgs/msg/point.hpp>` includes `<geometry_msgs/msg/detail/point__builder.hpp>`.